# How to run .exe file from pen drive on insert?

Tags: windows

I want to run a .exe file  (or) any application from pen drive on insert in to pc. I dont want to use Autorun.inf file, as all anti virus software's blocks it. I have used portable application launcher also, that also using autorun only. so once again anti virus software blocks it. Is there any alternative option, such that .exe file from pen drive should start automatically on pen drive insert?

Comment: Use a WMI script, maybe? See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277765/finding-usb-drive-letter-with-vbscript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autorun when USB stick is inserted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003386/autorun-when-usb-stick-is-inserted)

Comment: Why?  Are you writing a virus?

Comment: My intension is, am having an Application(.exe format) in my pen drive. I will give it to other users.
So that, they can able to launch my application in their own PC on inserting pen drive.
Now two things I have to do,
1. The users should not able to copy my Application what I have given and another is,
2. On insert pen drive the application should launch in their PC without any onclick.

Comment: There's no good way to make the application run without the user's approval, but don't worry about it; nobody will mind.

Comment: As for your other requirement, the only way to stop people copying the application would be to install a rootkit, which is (a) unethical; (b) probably illegal, depending on the relevant jurisdiction(s); and (c) very very difficult.  Instead, consider other solutions, such as getting the user to sign a contract and distributing each copy of the application with an embedded serial number.  Another common approach is for the application to only run if the user has a license code based on a unique ID such as the ethernet address.

Answer (score 2):

Anti-virus programs block autorun.inf on the solely purpose not to allow some .exe-s to start automatically on pen drive insert. So, basically, what you're asking is impossible.

Comment: Is their any other way to run an .exe file from pendrive without using autorun.exe ? And i want to run this from not only in my PC and also other user PC as well.

Comment: One can cheat and implement a program that would run in the background and check for the device arrival and execute the .exe from it. Perhaps, this could be done using standard Windows tools (tasks and PowerShell scripts).

Comment: @karthik If you want it to run on an arbitrary user's PC (and not one you are managing), the only way is to ask user to run it manually. Otherwise, all hackers of the world would put such autorunnable viruses on everybody's thumb drives (as they did 10 years ago).

Comment: For example, How the Reliance Net Connect Broadband plus USB Modem (like pen drive) will do the Auto Installation of software while inserting the USB Modem on PC’s?
Like that we can able to achieve this? Is this Possible.

Comment: @karthik Obviously, it uses the autorun feature. The autorun feature **is** a vulnerability, that's why it is disabled by default. Now you're asking about something like autorun which is not disabled; in fact, you want another autorun with another name. It is pointless.

Comment: Installing drivers for hardware is NOT autorun. A USB modem is not a device for which standard drivers are used; therefore Windows will download and install the correct drivers. Pendrives do use standard drivers (USB Mass Storage, to be precise) so there's no driver software downloaded for them.

Answer (score 0):

I havent used Windows in a long time, but I am fairly sure there is a setting in Windows to enable/disable autorunning executeables on mounted drives. That and changing such setting in your antivirus application (or get a new, saner one) would be my best guess.

Good luck!