# Run batch file from usb flash when it's connected to pc

Tags: windows, batch-file, autorun

i need a method for executing a batch file or a .exe file from usb flash right after it's connected to pc.
the batch file or .exe file will copy another file (which is in the flash too) to a folder in pc

i tried autorun.inf but neither batch file or .exe file run after plug in .

is there any way for doing this ??

thanks in advance 
MA

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autorun when USB stick is inserted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003386/autorun-when-usb-stick-is-inserted)

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, this feature has been disabled for several years now.

There is no way to get this to work anymore.

Comment: oh thanks, but how about cellphones or external hards , for the first time when you connect them to pc , if their drivers has not been installed , they will be installed automatically . am i right ??

Comment: If they are available on the host, yes.  But that is completely different that auto-running content from the device.